# Saving one vector variable on to another in python

Tags: python

I have a script that requires to transfer values of one vector onto another.
Code looks like:

```
b  = [1,2,3]

for i ranging from (0,2): 
   a[i] = b[i] #(transfer all three elements of b to a)
```

Doing this gets an error

```
- IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

What am i missing ? Thanks for help.

Comment: Looks like `a` is shorter, thus the error

Comment: Two minor points: `for i ranging from (0, 2):` isn't valid Python syntax, and even if it were, Python's conventions are left-closed-right-open on index ranges, so `(0, 2)` would probably only transfer 0 and 1: e.g. `list(range(0, 2)) == [0, 1]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = b[:]
```

should more than suffice

Answer (score 1):

the `list` needs to be the right size if you are referencing it by index.  ie. The `list` `a` doesn't have 3 elements.  I'd just create a new list with a list constructor or even easier do this

```
a = list(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have a script that requires to transfer values of one vector onto another

I think there is some confusion here between the *variable* and its *content*:

```
>>> a = [10,20]
>>> b = [1,2,3]
>>> c = a

>>> a,b,c
([10, 20], [1, 2, 3], [10, 20])
```

This create *two* lists. With two variables (`a` and `c`) *referencing* the same one.

If you write:

```
>>> a = [10,20]
>>> b = [1,2,3]
>>> c = a
>>> a = b[:]

>>> a,b,c
([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [10, 20])
```

You actually create a third list. An bind it to the variable `a`. But `c` still hold a reference to the original list.

If you want to really alter the original list, write that instead:

```
>>> a = [10,20]
>>> b = [1,2,3]
>>> c = a
>>> a[:] = b[:]  # "replace every item of the first list 
                 #  by every item of the second list"

>>> a,b,c
([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
```